# Two-Way Contingency Table with frequencies and percentages

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, contingency, janitor

I got the following Two-way contingency table with cell percentages along with frequencies (in parentheses).

```
gender       blue blue-gray       brown      dark      hazel    yellow
 female 33.33% (3) 0.00% (0) 55.56%  (5) 0.00% (0) 11.11% (1) 0.00% (0)
   male 34.62% (9) 3.85% (1) 46.15% (12) 3.85% (1)  3.85% (1) 7.69% (2)
```

The `R` code I used is

```
library(dplyr)

library(janitor)

starwars %>%
  filter(species == "Human") %>% 
  tabyl(gender, eye_color) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
  adorn_ns()
```

However, I want to get the same kind of table with cell frequencies along with percentages (in parentheses). Any help, please.

Comment: Do you want `(33.33%) (3)`.  Try  `%>% mutate_at(-1, list(~ str_replace(., "^([0-9.%]+)", "(\\1)")))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your comment. However, I want something like this `3 (33.33%)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can change the `position` argument in `adorn_ns` from `rear` (default) to `front`

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>%
  filter(species == "Human") %>% 
   tabyl(gender, eye_color) %>%
   adorn_percentages("row") %>%
   adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
   adorn_ns(position = "front")
# gender       blue blue-gray       brown      dark      hazel    yellow
# female 3 (33.33%) 0 (0.00%)  5 (55.56%) 0 (0.00%) 1 (11.11%) 0 (0.00%)
#   male 9 (34.62%) 1 (3.85%) 12 (46.15%) 1 (3.85%) 1  (3.85%) 2 (7.69%)
```

---

Or another option if the object is already created would be post-processswith `mutate_at` to change the formatting of all the columns except the first by capturing the characters in two blocks, reverse the positions by reversing the backreference while adding `()` for the percentage

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>%
  filter(species == "Human") %>% 
  tabyl(gender, eye_color) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
  adorn_ns() %>% 
  mutate_at(-1, list(~ str_replace(., "^([0-9.%]+)\\s+\\((\\d+)\\)", "\\2 (\\1)")))
# gender       blue blue-gray       brown      dark      hazel    yellow
#1 female 3 (33.33%) 0 (0.00%)  5 (55.56%) 0 (0.00%) 1 (11.11%) 0 (0.00%)
#2   male 9 (34.62%) 1 (3.85%) 12 (46.15%) 1 (3.85%)  1 (3.85%) 2 (7.69%)
```